# what will be the return value of GetCurSel

Tags: c++, mfc

I have list of users in my application and I have selected two users. My doubt is, if I call GetCurSel after selecting two users, GetCurSel will be having two users or the last selected user?
please clarify.

Comment: Ask yourself this: How would the function, which returns the result through a normal function return value, be able to return two or more values?

Comment: Did you try setting your cursor in the word "GetCurSel" and then pressing F1?

Comment: My question is after selecting two users, GetCurSel will be having focus of the two users or the last selected user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/6ty0th77%28v=vs.110%29.aspx I got the following:

```
int CListBox::GetCurSel( ) const
```

returns a single integer value. You always get the index of one list box entry. You will never get the indices of two entries with this function.

Reading further I learn:

> In a multiple-selection list box, [the method returns] the index of the item that has the focus. [..] Do not call GetCurSel for a multiple-selection list box. Use CListBox::GetSelItems instead.

The documentation for the latter can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ds24bscf.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the info.I am using CComboBox::GetCurSel to get the current selection. I need to send SMS to the selected users but I am able to send SMS for only last selected user.

Comment: A combobox is not meant for multi-selection. Use a list box instead!